# Network error handling for Android/Google Daydream (Unity)

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, unity-game-engine, networking

Best way to create a UDP network for Android

I recently asked a question regarding threading on Android (Google Daydream specific) which wasn't performing as expected. I was using a thread for communication to transfer information between an embedded system, and once the communication failed (i.e. the embedded system turned off, or any other 'can't transmit/receive' reason) the thread would abort and would attempt to reconnect to the embedded system until a connection is made again.

This works perfectly running in Unity (5.6) on Windows, but once ported to Android the thread seems to just hang once the network goes down and won't acknowledge that the thread has died. The Update() function continues to loop, but it's not until I leave the scene that the thread dies and the code continues to perform as expected ([see my other post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836769/google-daydream-thread-with-unity)).

I'm trying a new idea now where I'm assuming it's not the threading code which is problematic, or Android's inability to handle threads (as I've had no indication from anyone that what I'm doing can't be done on Android) but perhaps the handling of networks on Android or my UDP code.

I've got my UDP code below and I wanted to see if anyone saw anything which immediately looks wrong:

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System; 
using System.Net; 
using System.Net.Sockets;

public class UDPConn : MonoBehaviour {
    Socket sock;
    IPEndPoint destEnd;
    IPEndPoint endPoint;
    EndPoint sender;
    // Bool for connection status
    public bool socketReady = false;
    // Receive timeout (ms).
    int rxTimeout = 1000;
    byte[] msg;

    // Try to initiate connection.
    public bool setupSocket(int conPort)
    {
        try
        {
            String hostName = "";
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    hostName = ip.ToString();
                }
            }

            System.Net.IPAddress ipaddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(hostName);
            endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipaddress, conPort);

            System.Net.IPAddress remoteIP = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.20.2");
            destEnd = new IPEndPoint(remoteIP, conPort);
            sender = (EndPoint)destEnd;

            sock = new Socket(endPoint.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            sock.Bind(endPoint);
            sock.ReceiveTimeout = rxTimeout;

            // Send message to 'wake' other side.
            sock.SendTo(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Connect"), sender);

            // Attempt to read from the socket. This will timeout if the other side isn't active.
            string readData = readSocket();
            if (readData != null) {
                socketReady = true;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                socketReady = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Socket error: " + e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Send message to server.
    public void writeSocket(string theLine)
    {
        if (!socketReady)
        {
            return;
        }
        sock.SendTo(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(theLine), sender);
    }

    // Read message from server.
    public string readSocket()
    {
        try
        {
            msg = new Byte[256];
            sock.ReceiveFrom(msg, ref sender);
            String returnData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg);
            return returnData;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Socket error: " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Disconnect from the socket.
    public void closeSocket()
    {
        if (!socketReady)
        {
            return;
        }
        Debug.Log("UDPConn:closeSocket");
        sock.Close();
        socketReady = false;
    }
 }
```

Other than my code, I also saved the Logcat (see end of post) at the point of where I disconnected the network from the Android phone (by swiping down from the screen, disabling the WiFi). My other idea outside of the UDP code is that perhaps I need to catch some sort of network error from Android and handle it better. The first item in Logcat is the last Debug.Log message I sent within Unity, and the first cnss-daemon message is the point at which I disconnected the network. Is there anything in there that can help identify my issue?

Thanks very much for any help. Sorry for the long post.

```
06-30 14:07:56.150 19762 19966 I Unity   : **Inside Thread Run()
06-30 14:07:56.150 19762 19966 I Unity   : Stacktrace is not supported on this platform.
06-30 14:07:56.150 19762 19966 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
06-30 14:07:56.150 19762 19966 I Unity   :
06-30 14:07:56.149   651   651 W cnss-daemon: type=1400 audit(0.0:153): avc: granted { net_admin } for capability=12 scontext=u:r:cnss-daemon:s0 tcontext=u:r:cnss-daemon:s0 tclass=capability
06-30 14:07:56.149   651   651 W cnss-daemon: type=1400 audit(0.0:154): avc: granted { net_admin } for capability=12 scontext=u:r:cnss-daemon:s0 tcontext=u:r:cnss-daemon:s0 tclass=capability
06-30 14:07:56.149   651   651 W cnss-daemon: type=1400 audit(0.0:155): avc: granted { net_admin } for capability=12 scontext=u:r:cnss-daemon:s0 tcontext=u:r:cnss-daemon:s0 tclass=capability
06-30 14:07:56.149   651   651 W cnss-daemon: type=1400 audit(0.0:156): avc: granted { net_admin } for capability=12 scontext=u:r:cnss-daemon:s0 tcontext=u:r:cnss-daemon:s0 tclass=capability
06-30 14:07:56.149   651   651 W cnss-daemon: type=1400 audit(0.0:157): avc: granted { net_admin } for capability=12 scontext=u:r:cnss-daemon:s0 tcontext=u:r:cnss-daemon:s0 tclass=capability
06-30 14:07:56.149   651   651 W cnss-daemon: type=1400 audit(0.0:158): avc: granted { net_admin } for capability=12 scontext=u:r:cnss-daemon:s0 tcontext=u:r:cnss-daemon:s0 tclass=capability
06-30 14:07:56.153  1487  1487 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=de:14:5c:9c:33:94 reason=3 locally_generated=1
06-30 14:07:56.154  1487  1487 W wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Was expecting local disconnect but got another disconnect event first
06-30 14:07:56.160  1110  1455 D WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine: Leaving Connected state
06-30 14:07:56.164  1110  1456 D DhcpClient: doQuit
06-30 14:07:56.170  1110  1456 D ApfFilter: (wlan0): shutting down
06-30 14:07:56.171  1110  1455 D WifiNative-HAL: stopRssiMonitoring, cmdId 0
06-30 14:07:56.174  1110 19709 D DhcpClient: Receive thread stopped
06-30 14:07:56.177  1110  1459 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 110] EVENT_NETWORK_INFO_CHANGED, going from CONNECTED to DISCONNECTED
06-30 14:07:56.177  1110  1459 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 110] got DISCONNECTED, was satisfying 8
06-30 14:07:56.177  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK OFF using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:07:56.189   639  1171 D CommandListener: Setting iface cfg
06-30 14:07:56.200  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK ON using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:07:56.206  1110 19707 D DhcpClient: onQuitting
06-30 14:07:56.223  1682  1752 W QCNEJ   : |CORE| network lost: 110
06-30 14:07:56.224  1682  1752 W QCNEJ   : |CORE| onLost: unbind the process to WIFI
06-30 14:07:56.229  1487  1487 I wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
06-30 14:07:56.238   639  1171 D CommandListener: Clearing all IP addresses on wlan0
06-30 14:07:56.244  1110  1455 D WifiCountryCode: Succeeded to set country code to: US
06-30 14:07:56.244  1110  1455 D WifiStateMachine: Start Disconnecting Watchdog 11
06-30 14:07:56.245  1110  1455 D WifiNative-HAL: stopRssiMonitoring, cmdId 0
06-30 14:07:56.256  1110  1455 I WifiConnectivityManager: scheduleWatchdogTimer
06-30 14:07:56.277  2037  2453 W Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
06-30 14:07:56.282  1110  1455 I WifiConnectivityManager: Set WiFi disabled
06-30 14:07:56.283  1110  1455 D WifiNetworkAgent: NetworkAgent: NetworkAgent channel lost
06-30 14:07:56.297   639  1171 V IdletimerController: runCmd(/system/bin/ip6tables -w -t raw -D idletimer_raw_PREROUTING -i wlan0 -j IDLETIMER --timeout 15 --label 1 --send_nl_msg 1) res_ipv4=0, res_ipv6=0
06-30 14:07:56.310  2037  2453 W Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
06-30 14:07:56.330   639  1171 V IdletimerController: runCmd(/system/bin/ip6tables -w -t mangle -D idletimer_mangle_POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j IDLETIMER --timeout 15 --label 1 --send_nl_msg 1) res_ipv4=0, res_ipv6=0
06-30 14:07:56.332  1110  1459 D ConnectivityService: Sending DISCONNECTED broadcast for type 1 NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 110] isDefaultNetwork=true
06-30 14:07:56.344 18824 18824 D MusicLifecycle: com.google.android.music.net.NetworkConnectivityMonitor$NetworkChangedReceiver generated event: Broadcast received with context com.google.android.music.ui.PhoneMusicApplication@e91968c and intent Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
06-30 14:07:56.349  2393 18279 W MdnsClient_Cast: Multicast lock held. Releasing. Subtypes:"233637DE"
06-30 14:07:56.359 18824 18824 I NetworkConnectivity: Network state changed: null
06-30 14:07:56.372  2393 18279 W MdnsClient: unicast receiver thread is already dead.
06-30 14:07:56.384 18824 18824 I NetworkPolicyMonitor: Download-ability status changed to (false) unmetered wifi/eth: false mobileOrMetered: false
06-30 14:07:56.389 18824 18824 I NetworkPolicyMonitor: Stream-ability status changed to (false) unmetered wifi/eth: false mobileOrMetered: false
06-30 14:07:56.408  2393 18279 I DeviceScanner: [MDNS] notifyDevicesOffline: []
06-30 14:07:56.422  2393 18279 E Publisher: ProcessDatabaseInternal start
06-30 14:07:56.424  2393 18279 I CastMediaRouteProvider: onDevicesPublished with 0 devices
06-30 14:07:56.438  2393 18279 I CastMediaRouteProvider: Published 0 routes
06-30 14:07:56.447  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK OFF using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:07:56.452  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK ON using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:07:56.462   639  1171 E Netd    : netlink response contains error (No such file or directory)
06-30 14:07:56.464  1110  1459 D NetworkNotificationManager: clearing notification tag=ConnectivityNotification:110 event=NO_INTERNET
06-30 14:07:56.490  2393 14149 W Herrevad: [660] rwh.b: Invalid mccmnc
06-30 14:07:56.495  2393 14149 W Herrevad: [660] rwh.b: Invalid mccmnc
06-30 14:07:56.525 18824 18935 W NetworkBandwidthMonitor: Unsuccessful attempt to get a Network Quality Client prediction (quality==null)
06-30 14:07:56.552  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK OFF using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:07:56.557  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK ON using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:07:56.673  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK OFF using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:07:56.677  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK ON using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:07:56.732  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK OFF using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:07:56.737  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK ON using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:07:59.732  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK OFF using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:07:59.752  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK ON using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:08:00.872  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK OFF using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:08:00.877  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK ON using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:08:02.680  2164  2181 W GvrApi  : GvrApi.shutdown() should be called to ensure resource cleanup
06-30 14:08:04.847  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK OFF using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:08:04.852  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK ON using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:08:21.718  1110  1670 E         : E/int izat_xtra::XtraDataRequest::doDownloadXtraData(const string &, string &):177][XTRA2] DNS resolution on xtrapath3.izatcloud.net failed.
06-30 14:08:24.766  2037 19816 W ctxmgr  : [NetworkStateProducer]No state change for network connection context
06-30 14:08:26.012  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK OFF using UART driver's ioctl()
06-30 14:08:26.017  1930  1930 I WCNSS_FILTER: ibs_msm_serial_clock_vote: vote UART CLK ON using UART driver's ioctl()
```

Comment: you try with async callback and checking size of received data?

Comment: Thread handling can differ among operating systems and in mobiles it is even more sensitive. Over the iterations Android has been actively taking steps to protect against zombie threads and background threads which eat up battery and resources. As for communication, i don't see any apparent issues with your approach. If your application needs to run in the background, do check if your application has required permissions. Perhaps to fine tune, you can reduce the packet size being exchanged and reduce buffer size. But apart from that all looks good to me